# ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2-binary==2.8.2

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, python-3.9

Please how should i install psycopg2-binary on my python image.

I tried **pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.2** but i got this error

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2-binary==2.8.2 (from versions: 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.6.1, 2.7.7, 2.8, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.9, 2.9.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2-binary==2.8.2`

My image is **python3.9-alpine**

What should i do please???

Answer (score 4):

Given the amount of work that requires to be done, I suggest you use a different base image, e.g. `python:3.9` or that you install the alpine package [py3-psycopg2](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/py3-psycopg2) (which is on v 2.8.6 at the time of writing).

Anyway I tried it on my machine and in the error it's also written `Error: pg_config executable not found.`

The pg_config is part of the [postgres_dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=postgresql-dev&arch=x86) package and needs to be installed before installing the `psycopg2-binary` package.

The psycopg2-binary will also need the gcc to be installed and some other libraries.

In other words, you have to execute the following commands:

```sh
apk add postgresql-dev gcc ...
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
```

I've abandoned the topic after I had to install a bunch of libraries.

Comment: Hello @Stefano ! Thank you for your help . I got this error **apk not found** when trying this line apk add postgresql-dev gcc ... i think because its debian distribution

Comment: just to be on the same page. I've executed the following: `docker run -it --rm python:3.9-alpine sh`. Once inside the container, I've executed `apk add postgresql-dev gcc`. As I wrote in the answer, the list is not complete. There's quite an amount of libraries to install as well

Comment: did the same and got this error **bash: apk: command not found**

Comment: I don't think you did. Alpine comes without `bash`. You would not get that error.

Comment: it's not an alpine distribution ? Am i wrong.?

Comment: e.g. if I execute `docker run -it --rm python:3.9-alpine bash`, I receive `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236408/discussion-between-stefano-and-charles).